# How to avoid splitting float numbers while using Wordninja?

Tags: python, string, split

I am working on cleaning textual data. I have a column that shows description of products. Some words are adjacent. I used [wordninja](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) for splitting words.

It worked well but it split the float numbers. I want to use these numbers as it is.

Is there a way to avoid split floats while using wordninja?

```
import wordninja  
def split_adjacent_words(description):
    words = wordninja.split(description)
    return" ".join(words)

df['description_clean'] = df[df['description'].isna()==False]['description'].apply(lambda x : split_adjacent_words(x))
```

Comment: Preprocess a string to split around float numbers using a regular expression. Try something like ```re.finditer('\d+(?:\.\d+)?', s)```.